# Iptable rules preventing me from connecting to docker proxy running on localhost

Tags: docker, iptables, socks

I'm having trouble connecting to socks5 proxy running via docker on localhost. 
When i flush the iptable rules everything works fine.
But they are there because of the openvpn server.
So I need to be able to modify them to allow me to route the server's localhost to docker containers (on the same server) bound to port 9050 or others.

Here is my initial iptable rules (openvpn) (/etc/iptables/rules.v4)

```
*filter
# Allow all loopback (lo) traffic and reject anything
# to localhost that does not originate from lo.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping and ICMP error returns.
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow UDP traffic on port 1194.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS resolution and limited HTTP/S on eth0.
# Necessary for updating the server and timekeeping.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow traffic on the TUN interface so OpenVPN can communicate with eth0.
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

# Log any packets which don't fit the rules above.
# (optional but useful)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: " --log-level 4
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: " --log-level 4
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_OUTPUT_denied: " --log-level 4

# then reject them.
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

Port looks to be open.

```
➜  ~ nc -zv 127.0.0.1 9050
localhost [127.0.0.1] 9050 (?) open
```

Am I missing a forward to the docker containers?
Could "-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable" be causing this?

I've tried both with curl on the server, and with the python code included.

**Python code**

```
import requests
import socks

    def main():
        print("test")
        session = requests.session()
        session.proxies = {}

        session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
        session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'

        r = session.get('http://icanhazip.com')
        print(r.text)
```

Here is my iptable rules.

```
sudo iptables --table nat --list
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !loopback/8           ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
MASQUERADE  all  --  <hidden>/24         anywhere            
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:6379
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:9050

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             localhost            tcp dpt:6379 to:172.17.0.2:6379
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             localhost            tcp dpt:9050 to:172.17.0.3:9050
```

**output of iptables -s**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s <hidden>/24 -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_FORWARD_denied: "
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m udp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_OUTPUT_denied: "
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -s <hidden>/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```

Comment: This is definetly an iptables issue. Flushed all rules and everything is working. So how to i modify current rules to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can find what rules are causing the problems in `/var/log/syslog`.

My guess is that you need to add the following INPUT and OUTPUT chain rules before the reject rules:

```
-A INPUT -i docker0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 9050 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o docker0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
```

These should be placed before the:

```
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_INPUT_denied: "
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

and:

```
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables_OUTPUT_denied: "
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

respectively.  You'll need to add similar rules for any other ports you expose with other containers.

EDIT:  If you switch to using docker-compose, this will be slightly different.  Comment if you end up in this situation and need help.

Also, another common problem is that the application running in the docker container is bound to 127.0.0.1 or localhost.  localhost inside a docker container is not the same localhost as the docker host, so you'll be unable to connect to the container via the docker host.  Typically applications built as docker containers have config files or options that you can specify the IP to bind on -- use 0.0.0.0 here.